# Creating Scene In android game

Tags: android, android-widget

I am new to android game development using andengine. I am trying to create a scene that will consist of a static tree and a player that can move and control with the help of some controls. I have created a player which is moving and also can be control with some controller, but now when I add a static tree then it give an error.

Here is the code and logcat errors:

```
package se.treplex.sketchytruck;

import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

import org.anddev.andengine.engine.Engine;
import org.anddev.andengine.engine.camera.Camera;
import org.anddev.andengine.engine.camera.hud.controls.AnalogOnScreenControl;
import org.anddev.andengine.engine.camera.hud.controls.BaseOnScreenControl;
import org.anddev.andengine.engine.camera.hud.controls.AnalogOnScreenControl.IAnalogOnScreenControlListener;
import org.anddev.andengine.engine.handler.physics.PhysicsHandler;
import org.anddev.andengine.engine.options.EngineOptions;
import org.anddev.andengine.engine.options.EngineOptions.ScreenOrientation;
import org.anddev.andengine.engine.options.resolutionpolicy.RatioResolutionPolicy;
import org.anddev.andengine.entity.modifier.ScaleModifier;
import org.anddev.andengine.entity.modifier.SequenceEntityModifier;
import org.anddev.andengine.entity.scene.Scene;
import org.anddev.andengine.entity.scene.background.ColorBackground;
import org.anddev.andengine.entity.sprite.Sprite;
import org.anddev.andengine.entity.util.FPSLogger;
import org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.TextureOptions;
import org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.BitmapTextureAtlas;
import org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory;
import org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.region.TextureRegion;

import android.widget.Toast;

public class demo1 extends BaseExample{
    private static final int CAMERA_WIDTH = 600;
    private static final int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 800;

    // ===========================================================
    // Fields
    // ===========================================================

    private Camera mCamera;

    private BitmapTextureAtlas mBitmapTextureAtlas;
    private TextureRegion mFaceTextureRegion;

    private BitmapTextureAtlas mOnScreenControlTexture,treeatlas;
    private TextureRegion mOnScreenControlBaseTextureRegion,treergn;
    private TextureRegion mOnScreenControlKnobTextureRegion;

    // ===========================================================
    // Constructors
    // ===========================================================

    // ===========================================================
    // Getter & Setter
    // ===========================================================

    // ===========================================================
    // Methods for/from SuperClass/Interfaces
    // ===========================================================

    @Override
    public Engine onLoadEngine() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Also try tapping this AnalogOnScreenControl!",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        this.mCamera = new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
        return new Engine(new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.PORTRAIT,
                new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT),
                this.mCamera));
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadResources() {
        BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.setAssetBasePath("gfx/");

        this.mBitmapTextureAtlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(32, 32,
                TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);
        this.mFaceTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory
                .createFromAsset(this.mBitmapTextureAtlas, this,
                        "face.png", 0, 0);

        this.mOnScreenControlTexture = new BitmapTextureAtlas(256, 128,
                TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);
        this.mOnScreenControlBaseTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory
                .createFromAsset(this.mOnScreenControlTexture, this,
                        "onscreen_control_base.png", 0, 0);


        this.mOnScreenControlKnobTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory
                .createFromAsset(this.mOnScreenControlTexture, this,
                        "onscreen_control_knob.png", 128, 0);

        this.mEngine.getTextureManager().loadTextures(this.mBitmapTextureAtlas,
                this.mOnScreenControlTexture);

        //for tree 
                this.treeatlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(1024, 1024,
                        TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);
                this.treergn = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory
                        .createFromAsset(this.mOnScreenControlTexture, this,
                                "gfx/treedemo.png", 0, 0);
                this.mEngine.getTextureManager().loadTexture(treeatlas);
    }

    @Override
    public Scene onLoadScene() {
        this.mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new FPSLogger());

        final Scene scene = new Scene();
        scene.setBackground(new ColorBackground(0.09804f, 0.6274f, 0.8784f));

        //for tree
        final Sprite treesprt = new Sprite(10, 0,
                this.mFaceTextureRegion);


        scene.attachChild(treesprt);


        final int centerX = (CAMERA_WIDTH - this.mFaceTextureRegion.getWidth()) / 2;
        final int centerY = (CAMERA_HEIGHT - this.mFaceTextureRegion
                .getHeight()) / 2;
        final Sprite face = new Sprite(centerX, centerY,
                this.mFaceTextureRegion);
        final PhysicsHandler physicsHandler = new PhysicsHandler(face);
        face.registerUpdateHandler(physicsHandler);

        scene.attachChild(face);



        final AnalogOnScreenControl analogOnScreenControl = new AnalogOnScreenControl(
                0, CAMERA_HEIGHT
                        - this.mOnScreenControlBaseTextureRegion.getHeight(),
                this.mCamera, this.mOnScreenControlBaseTextureRegion,
                this.mOnScreenControlKnobTextureRegion, 0.1f, 200,
                new IAnalogOnScreenControlListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onControlChange(
                            final BaseOnScreenControl pBaseOnScreenControl,
                            final float pValueX, final float pValueY) {
                        physicsHandler
                                .setVelocity(pValueX * 100, pValueY * 100);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onControlClick(
                            final AnalogOnScreenControl pAnalogOnScreenControl) {
                        face.registerEntityModifier(new SequenceEntityModifier(
                                new ScaleModifier(0.25f, 1, 1.5f),
                                new ScaleModifier(0.25f, 1.5f, 1)));
                    }
                });
        analogOnScreenControl.getControlBase().setBlendFunction(
                GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        analogOnScreenControl.getControlBase().setAlpha(0.5f);
        analogOnScreenControl.getControlBase().setScaleCenter(0, 128);
        analogOnScreenControl.getControlBase().setScale(1.25f);
        analogOnScreenControl.getControlKnob().setScale(1.25f);
        analogOnScreenControl.refreshControlKnobPosition();

        scene.setChildScene(analogOnScreenControl);

        return scene;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadComplete() {

    }
}
```

Logcat:

```
03-20 14:40:42.343: E/AndEngine(25980): Failed loading Bitmap in AssetBitmapTextureAtlasSource. AssetPath: gfx/face.png
03-20 14:40:42.343: E/AndEngine(25980): java.io.FileNotFoundException: gfx/face.png
03-20 14:40:42.343: E/AndEngine(25980):     at android.content.res.AssetManager.openAsset(Native Method)
03-20 14:40:42.343: E/AndEngine(25980):     at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:314)
03-20 14:40:42.343: E/AndEngine(25980):     at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:288)
03-20 14:40:42.343: E/AndEngine(25980):     at org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.source.AssetBitmapTextureAtlasSource.<init>(AssetBitmapTextureAtlasSource.java:55)
03-20 14:40:42.343: E/AndEngine(25980):     at org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.source.AssetBitmapTextureAtlasSource.<init>(AssetBitmapTextureAtlasSource.java:42)
03-20 14:40:42.343: E/AndEngine(25980):     at org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.java:75)
03-20 14:40:42.343: E/AndEngine(25980):     at se.treplex.sketchytruck.demo1.onLoadResources(demo1.java:73)
03-20 14:40:42.343: E/AndEngine(25980):     at org.anddev.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity.doResume(BaseGameActivity.java:168)
03-20 14:40:42.343: E/AndEngine(25980):     at org.anddev.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity.onWindowFocusChanged(BaseGameActivity.java:85)
03-20 14:40:42.343: E/AndEngine(25980):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onWindowFocusChanged(PhoneWindow.java:2103)
03-20 14:40:42.343: E/AndEngine(25980):     at android.view.View.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(View.java:3924)
03-20 14:40:42.343: E/AndEngine(25980):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(ViewGroup.java:659)
03-20 14:40:42.343: E/AndEngine(25980):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1991)
03-20 14:40:42.343: E/AndEngine(25980):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-20 14:40:42.343: E/AndEngine(25980):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
03-20 14:40:42.343: E/AndEngine(25980):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
03-20 14:40:42.343: E/AndEngine(25980):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-20 14:40:42.343: E/AndEngine(25980):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-20 14:40:42.343: E/AndEngine(25980):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
03-20 14:40:42.343: E/AndEngine(25980):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
03-20 14:40:42.343: E/AndEngine(25980):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-20 14:40:42.367: E/AndEngine(25980): Failed loading Bitmap in AssetBitmapTextureAtlasSource. AssetPath: gfx/gfx/treedemo.png
03-20 14:40:42.367: E/AndEngine(25980): java.io.FileNotFoundException: gfx/gfx/treedemo.png
03-20 14:40:42.367: E/AndEngine(25980):     at android.content.res.AssetManager.openAsset(Native Method)
03-20 14:40:42.367: E/AndEngine(25980):     at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:314)
03-20 14:40:42.367: E/AndEngine(25980):     at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:288)
03-20 14:40:42.367: E/AndEngine(25980):     at org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.source.AssetBitmapTextureAtlasSource.<init>(AssetBitmapTextureAtlasSource.java:55)
03-20 14:40:42.367: E/AndEngine(25980):     at org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.source.AssetBitmapTextureAtlasSource.<init>(AssetBitmapTextureAtlasSource.java:42)
03-20 14:40:42.367: E/AndEngine(25980):     at org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.java:75)
03-20 14:40:42.367: E/AndEngine(25980):     at se.treplex.sketchytruck.demo1.onLoadResources(demo1.java:94)
03-20 14:40:42.367: E/AndEngine(25980):     at org.anddev.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity.doResume(BaseGameActivity.java:168)
03-20 14:40:42.367: E/AndEngine(25980):     at org.anddev.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity.onWindowFocusChanged(BaseGameActivity.java:85)
03-20 14:40:42.367: E/AndEngine(25980):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onWindowFocusChanged(PhoneWindow.java:2103)
03-20 14:40:42.367: E/AndEngine(25980):     at android.view.View.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(View.java:3924)
03-20 14:40:42.367: E/AndEngine(25980):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(ViewGroup.java:659)
03-20 14:40:42.367: E/AndEngine(25980):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1991)
03-20 14:40:42.367: E/AndEngine(25980):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-20 14:40:42.367: E/AndEngine(25980):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
03-20 14:40:42.367: E/AndEngine(25980):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
03-20 14:40:42.367: E/AndEngine(25980):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-20 14:40:42.367: E/AndEngine(25980):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-20 14:40:42.367: E/AndEngine(25980):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
03-20 14:40:42.367: E/AndEngine(25980):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
03-20 14:40:42.367: E/AndEngine(25980):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-20 14:40:42.687: D/libEGL(25980): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_hgl.so
03-20 14:40:42.757: E/(25980): Creating OpenGL 1.1 Session
03-20 14:40:42.796: D/BRCM_EGL(25980): eglCreateContext() context: 0x1b7618, VC context 1, Thread 26006
03-20 14:40:42.796: D/BRCM_EGL(25980): eglCreateWindowSurface() surface: 0x1dfcd0, VC surface: 1, Thread: 26006
03-20 14:40:42.796: D/BRCM_EGL(25980): eglMakeCurrent(0x1b7618, 0x1dfcd0, 0x1dfcd0) Thread: 26006
03-20 14:40:42.828: D/AndEngine(25980): onSurfaceCreated
03-20 14:40:42.851: D/AndEngine(25980): RENDERER: VideoCore IV HW
03-20 14:40:42.851: D/AndEngine(25980): VERSION: OpenGL ES-CM 1.1
03-20 14:40:42.851: D/AndEngine(25980): EXTENSIONS: GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture GL_OES_compressed_paletted_texture GL_OES_texture_npot GL_OES_EGL_image GL_EXT_discard_framebuffer GL_OES_query_matrix GL_OES_framebuffer_object GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8 GL_OES_depth24 GL_OES_depth32 GL_OES_stencil8 GL_OES_draw_texture
03-20 14:40:42.851: D/AndEngine(25980): EXTENSIONS_VERXTEXBUFFEROBJECTS = true
03-20 14:40:42.859: D/AndEngine(25980): EXTENSIONS_DRAWTEXTURE = true
03-20 14:40:42.859: D/AndEngine(25980): onSurfaceChanged: pWidth=240  pHeight=320
03-20 14:40:42.882: E/AndEngine(25980): Failed loading Bitmap in AssetBitmapTextureAtlasSource. AssetPath: gfx/face.png
03-20 14:40:42.882: E/AndEngine(25980): java.io.FileNotFoundException: gfx/face.png
03-20 14:40:42.882: E/AndEngine(25980):     at android.content.res.AssetManager.openAsset(Native Method)
03-20 14:40:42.882: E/AndEngine(25980):     at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:314)
03-20 14:40:42.882: E/AndEngine(25980):     at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:288)
03-20 14:40:42.882: E/AndEngine(25980):     at org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.source.AssetBitmapTextureAtlasSource.onLoadBitmap(AssetBitmapTextureAtlasSource.java:105)
03-20 14:40:42.882: E/AndEngine(25980):     at org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.BitmapTextureAtlas.writeTextureToHardware(BitmapTextureAtlas.java:156)
03-20 14:40:42.882: E/AndEngine(25980):     at org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.Texture.loadToHardware(Texture.java:116)
03-20 14:40:42.882: E/AndEngine(25980):     at org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.TextureManager.updateTextures(TextureManager.java:146)
03-20 14:40:42.882: E/AndEngine(25980):     at org.anddev.andengine.engine.Engine.onDrawFrame(Engine.java:503)
03-20 14:40:42.882: E/AndEngine(25980):     at org.anddev.andengine.opengl.view.RenderSurfaceView$Renderer.onDrawFrame(RenderSurfaceView.java:154)
03-20 14:40:42.882: E/AndEngine(25980):     at org.anddev.andengine.opengl.view.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:617)
03-20 14:40:42.882: E/AndEngine(25980):     at org.anddev.andengine.opengl.view.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:549)
03-20 14:40:42.890: E/AndEngine(25980): Error loading: AssetBitmapTextureAtlasSource(gfx/face.png)
03-20 14:40:42.890: E/AndEngine(25980): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AssetBitmapTextureAtlasSource: AssetBitmapTextureAtlasSource(gfx/face.png) returned a null Bitmap.
03-20 14:40:42.890: E/AndEngine(25980):     at org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.BitmapTextureAtlas.writeTextureToHardware(BitmapTextureAtlas.java:159)
03-20 14:40:42.890: E/AndEngine(25980):     at org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.Texture.loadToHardware(Texture.java:116)
03-20 14:40:42.890: E/AndEngine(25980):     at org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.TextureManager.updateTextures(TextureManager.java:146)
03-20 14:40:42.890: E/AndEngine(25980):     at org.anddev.andengine.engine.Engine.onDrawFrame(Engine.java:503)
03-20 14:40:42.890: E/AndEngine(25980):     at org.anddev.andengine.opengl.view.RenderSurfaceView$Renderer.onDrawFrame(RenderSurfaceView.java:154)
03-20 14:40:42.890: E/AndEngine(25980):     at org.anddev.andengine.opengl.view.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:617)
03-20 14:40:42.890: E/AndEngine(25980):     at org.anddev.andengine.opengl.view.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:549)
03-20 14:40:42.890: W/dalvikvm(25980): threadid=10: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
03-20 14:40:42.914: E/AndroidRuntime(25980): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread
03-20 14:40:42.914: E/AndroidRuntime(25980): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AssetBitmapTextureAtlasSource: AssetBitmapTextureAtlasSource(gfx/face.png) returned a null Bitmap.
03-20 14:40:42.914: E/AndroidRuntime(25980):    at org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.BitmapTextureAtlas.writeTextureToHardware(BitmapTextureAtlas.java:159)
03-20 14:40:42.914: E/AndroidRuntime(25980):    at org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.Texture.loadToHardware(Texture.java:116)
03-20 14:40:42.914: E/AndroidRuntime(25980):    at org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.TextureManager.updateTextures(TextureManager.java:146)
03-20 14:40:42.914: E/AndroidRuntime(25980):    at org.anddev.andengine.engine.Engine.onDrawFrame(Engine.java:503)
03-20 14:40:42.914: E/AndroidRuntime(25980):    at org.anddev.andengine.opengl.view.RenderSurfaceView$Renderer.onDrawFrame(RenderSurfaceView.java:154)
03-20 14:40:42.914: E/AndroidRuntime(25980):    at org.anddev.andengine.opengl.view.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:617)
03-20 14:40:42.914: E/AndroidRuntime(25980):    at org.anddev.andengine.opengl.view.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:549)
03-20 14:40:43.046: D/dalvikvm(25980): GC_CONCURRENT freed 297K, 49% free 2927K/5639K, external 417K/517K, paused 3ms+4ms
```

Comment: You forgot to add the logcat errors.

Comment: Thanks michal.. Now  i added the logcat error... Kindly check it and if have some solution then kindly tell me plz....

Comment: Failed loading Bitmap in AssetBitmapTextureAtlasSource. AssetPath: gfx/face.png

Comment: Thanks Fatima and michal for reply.Have u worked in android game ? Any one of u????

Answer (score 0):

Everything is said in the error :

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: gfx/face.png
```

The method `createFromAsset(...)` can't found the picture.

Are you sure this is the right path (`gfx/face.png`) to access to `face.png`? Is this picture in `gfx`?

Comment: Actually this project have already two bodies. i want to add third static body .. so as i add that body there it get error ... if u know any other solution then can tell me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. the image face.png not exist in assets/gfx folder.clearly mentioned in your logcat.
2. once you set gfx as a base path for assets

   ```
   BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.setAssetBasePath("gfx/");
   ```

   then no need to write gfx/ again in upcoming line of codes as you have write this here. so remove gfx/ from the code of lines below.

   ```
   this.treergn = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory
                   .createFromAsset(this.mOnScreenControlTexture, this,
                           "gfx/treedemo.png", 0, 0);
   ```